# Genus of $k(T)$ is $0$ without using Riemann-Roch

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, function-fields

Let $F$ be a function field with one variable with total constant field $k$, and let $X$ be the set of all places of $F$. How do I show that the genus of $k(T)$ is $0$ without using Riemann-Roch? Is there a way to do it a la establishing the surjectivity of $k[T] \to k((1/T))/k[[1/T]]$?

EDIT: My definition of genus is as follows. Let $S$ be a nonempty finite subset of $X$. Then the genus of $F$ is equal to the dimension over $k$ of the cokernel of $$O_S \to \bigoplus_{v \in S} F_v/O_v.$$

Comment: What is your definition of the genus of a function field over $k$?

Comment: I recommend that you look up "Lagrange interpolation".  That works best over an algebraically closed field, but surjectivity of your "principal parts homomorphism" can be checked after base change.